# eval and test_minibatch in cntk

Tags: python, deep-learning, cntk

We are using TrainResNet_CIFAR10.py  as an example to learn cntk.  We have created two methods, eval_metric and calc_error as below:

```
def eval_metric(trainer, reader_test, test_epoch_size, label_var, input_map) :
    # Evaluation parameters
    minibatch_size = 16

    # process minibatches and evaluate the model
    metric_numer    = 0
    metric_denom    = 0
    sample_count    = 0

    while sample_count < test_epoch_size:
        current_minibatch = min(minibatch_size, test_epoch_size - sample_count)
        # Fetch next test min batch.
        data = reader_test.next_minibatch(current_minibatch, input_map=input_map)
        # minibatch data to be trained with
        metric_numer += trainer.test_minibatch(data) * current_minibatch
        metric_denom += current_minibatch
        # Keep track of the number of samples processed so far.
        sample_count += data[label_var].num_samples

    return metric_numer / metric_denom

def calc_error(trainer, fileList, mean_value, test_size) :
    if (len(fileList) != test_size) :
        return 0

    n   = 0
    m = 0
    while n < test_size:
        c = evalute(trainer, fileList[n].filename, mean_value);
        if (c != fileList[n].classID) :
            m += 1 
        n += 1

    return m / test_size

def evalute(trainer, img_name, mean_value) :
    rgb_image = np.asarray(Image.open(img_name), dtype=np.float32) - mean_value
    bgr_image = rgb_image[..., [2, 1, 0]]
    pic = np.ascontiguousarray(np.rollaxis(bgr_image, 2))
    probs = trainer.eval({trainer.arguments[0]:[pic]})
    predictions = np.squeeze(probs)
    top_class = np.argmax(predictions)
    return top_class
```

We thought test_minibatch(data) returns percent of incorrect results and the two methods should give similar results.  My questions are:

1. What does trainer.test_minibatch(data) return?
2. For CIFAR-10 test images, the differences between the two methods are within 10%, but for our own sample images, which have 64x64x3 and 4 classes, the differences are more than 100%.  What could cause the large difference?
3. If we pass the trainer directly to calc_error, it gives error during eval. We have to save and load_model first before call calc_error, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`trainer.test_minibatch` returns the average value of the loss (or in general the first argument).

There are also these methods that you can use after calling `test_minibatch`:
`trainer.previous_minibatch_loss_average`, `trainer.previous_minibatch_sample_count`, and `trainer.previous_minibatch_evaluation_average`.

The differences are likely coming from pre-processing. Is the `mean_value` the same as when you trained the network? Is it in RGB order or in BGR order?

Have you considered reducing your evaluation set to a single image and verify that you get exactly the same output with the reader and by manually loading the image?

Comment: Nikos, great to know!  I've tried to call   trainer.previous_minibatch_evaluation_average
and trainer.previous_minibatch_loss_average right after test_minibatch, but I got "This Value object is invalid and can no longer be accessed" exception.  What could cause this error?  I have used the same mean_value for both train and test and tried both RGB and BGR order, but got similar results: calc_error gives much larger error than eval_metric.  Should we use RGB or BGR order in mean_value?  What do you mean by reducing evaluation set to a single image -- do you mean set minibatch_size to 1?

Comment: The "invalid" error is when you try to access something from a previous minibatch. Not sure why you are getting this. If the network was trained with CNTK's readers, you need BGR order. If you train it yourself, it depends on how data was loaded. I don't mean set minibatch_size to 1, I mean have a single image in your test set until you get identical results with all methods.

Comment: Good! Do you mean that mean_value should be BGR order during train, too, if train with CNTK's readers?  Is there anyway to call trainer.eval without having to save and load_model first?

Comment: The ImageDeserializer loads data in bgr order so the network is trained to do well on bgr images. So the right mean to subtract would be bgr ordered both in training and test. For your other question. You call eval on the model itself without any Trainer.

Comment: def verify_metric(z, fileList, mean_value) :
    test_size = len(fileList)

    cm = 0.0
    n = 0
    while n < test_size:
        top_class = evaluate(z, fileList[n].filename, mean_value)
        if (top_class != fileList[n].classID) :
            cm += 1
        n += 1

    return (cm / test_size)

Comment: I've created above method in hope to see if it returns the same or similar value as eval_metric.  verify_metric is typically returns 50% more than eval_metric.  I have tried subtracting mean from bgr_image instead of rgb_image, but still have similar problem. What could cause the problem?