# Getting loss for test image

Tags: cntk

I'm trying to get the loss from a test image in Faster R-CNN.

If I run `copy.copy(trainer.previous_minibatch_loss_average)` right after `trainer.train_minibatch(data)` then I can get the loss out for the trained image(mb=1).
When I try to do the exact same after `trainer.test_minibatch(data)` I get: *This Value object is invalid and can no longer be accessed*.

I've been looking around and it seems that other may have accomplish with something similar. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773598/eval-and-test-minibatch-in-cntk).

Anyone know what to do to get the loss of a test image?

Answer (score 0):

```
results = []
results.append(trainer.previous_minibatch_loss_average)
```

The above should work.